# Creating elements using javascript, that can be put into HTML elements through a loop

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to add elements to a HTML element (table), while also adding specific attributes to these elements. Consider the following:

```
<th class="tableTopContent">Day
     <svg class="svghidden">
          <line x1="0" y1="50%" x2="100%" y2="50%"/>
     </svg>
</th>
```

I want this to be created in Javascript, I have browsed a bit here and there and came up with:

```
        var a = document.createElement("th");
        var b = document.createElement("svg");
        b.classList.add("svghidden");
        var c = document.createElement("line");
        c.setAttribute("x1", "0%")
        c.setAttribute("y1", "50%")
        c.setAttribute("x2", "100%")
        c.setAttribute("y2","50%")
        a.appendChild(b);
        b.appendChild(c);
        document.getElementById("celldates").appendChild(a);
```

I find this to be quite messy, also it does not work. Any ideas on how to apply the first set of code properly, as javascript?

Comment: Could you describe what you mean by doesn’t work? The elements would seem to get created fine.

Comment: At first glance I thought I had done a mistake or written it wrong, as I usually do not transfer code from CSS /HTML to javascript this way. What I thought did not work seemed to work fine, I had just done a few mistakes when it came to referencing elements from JS to created HTML elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume "*celldates*" is the **TR** tag where the **TH** tag is being injected, correctly? If not, there is your answer...

Here is a simple HTML sample using the small script example provided demonstrating it DOES work:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>

    <table>
        <tr id="celldates">
        </tr>
    </table>

    <script>
            var a = document.createElement("th");
            var b = document.createElement("svg");
            b.classList.add("svghidden");
            var c = document.createElement("line");
            c.setAttribute("x1", "0%")
            c.setAttribute("y1", "50%")
            c.setAttribute("x2", "100%")
            c.setAttribute("y2","50%")
            a.appendChild(b);
            b.appendChild(c);
            document.getElementById("celldates").appendChild(a);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

You won't see anything on the screen because there is no color specified for the CSV lines. Nevertheless, you can inspect the code (F12 in Chrome) and you will notice the browser did create the **TH** with the **SVG** inside via the Javascript code provided.

About the code, it is not messy, it is very simple. Wherever you found it, it seems to have been a very didactical place trying to demonstrate how the process works. All good.

Comment: Greetings, and thanks for the response.

You are correct, the 'celldates' ID is the ID of the TR element. 
They are also supposed to have no color for other reasons, it seems I had done some minor mistakes within the code itself which did not add them properly, but it seems to work fine now thanks to you. :-)